# Change background color of ListTile upon selection in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout, background-color

I've made a `ListView` in Flutter, but now I have some `ListTiles` in this `ListView` that can be selected. Upon selection, I want the background color to change to a color of my choice. I don't know how to do that.
In [the docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTileTheme/style.html) they mention that a `ListTile` has a property `style`. However, when I try to add that (as in third last line in the code below), this `style` property gets a squiggly red line underneath and the compiler tells me that `The named parameter 'style' isn't defined`.

```
Widget _buildRow(String string){
  return new ListTile(
    title: new Text(string),
    onTap: () => setState(() => toggleSelection(string)),
    selected: selectedFriends.contains(string),
    style: new ListTileTheme(selectedColor: Colors.white,),
  );
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58092611/10511266 might help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not `ListTile` that has the `style` property. But `ListTileTheme`. 
`ListTileTheme` is an inheritedWidget. And like others, it's used to pass *down* data (such as theme here).

To use it, you have to wrap any widget **above** your ListTile with a `ListTileTheme` containing the desired values.

`ListTile` will then theme itself depending on the closest `ListTileTheme` instance.

Comment: Unfortunately, `ListTileTheme` doesn't have a backgroundColor property, just a selectedColor property.
```this.dense = false,

    this.style = ListTileStyle.list,
    this.selectedColor,
    this.iconColor,
    this.textColor,
    this.contentPadding,
```

Edit: RIP Formatting

Comment: this is the marked correct answer, however, am still not sure how to change the background colour.

Answer (score 54):

#### Screenshot:

[image]

---

#### Short answer:

```dart
ListTile(
  tileColor: isSelected ? Colors.blue : null, 
)
```

---

#### Full Code:

```dart
// You can also use `Map` but for the sake of simplicity I'm using two separate `List`.
final List<int> _list = List.generate(20, (i) => i);
final List<bool> _selected = List.generate(20, (i) => false); // Fill it with false initially
  
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (_, i) {
        return ListTile(
          tileColor: _selected[i] ? Colors.blue : null, // If current item is selected show blue color
          title: Text('Item ${_list[i]}'),
          onTap: () => setState(() => _selected[i] = !_selected[i]), // Reverse bool value
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: How to select only one at the time and deselect the previous selected?

Comment: @Richardd Create a variable `int selectedIndex = -1`, and then check `if (index == selectedIndex)` approach. If you didn't get that, please ask a separate questions, I'll answer it.

Comment: I tried to implement your idea, but I think I did not understood it well. Can you have a look in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64655361/flutter-how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-selected-tile-from-a-listtile Thanks

Comment: @Richardd I was about to write the answer now, but just saw someone else already did that and he used the same approach I mentioned :)

Answer (score 43):

I was able to change the background color of the ListTile using a **BoxDecoration** inside **Container**:

```
ListView (
    children: <Widget>[
        new Container (
            decoration: new BoxDecoration (
                color: Colors.red
            ),
            child: new ListTile (
                leading: const Icon(Icons.euro_symbol),
                title: Text('250,00')
            )
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: The color property of Container() will suffice too.

Comment: The downside of this is that you won't have any splash or hover effects. To fix it just wrap the tile with `Theme` and override `focusColor`

Answer (score 30):

If you also need an `onTap` listener with a ripple effect, you can use `Ink`:

```
ListView(
  children: [
    Ink(
      color: Colors.lightGreen,
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text('With lightGreen background'),
        onTap: () { },
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

[image: Ripple Effect]

Comment: @Augusto do you care about being more specific what is not working? It certainly does for me..

Comment: I've copied and paste your code, and when I click on item the color not is showed...

Comment: @Augusto what do you mean? the color should ALWAYS be visible. On tap only the ripple effect should be added. SO what exactly is your problem.

Comment: If I was wrong I'll remove my comment. I want show ripple effect when user click on the option, I've copied it and not happens. I don't want put color, just effect.

Comment: @Augusto the ListTile already includes a `InkWell`, which is the only thing you need for a ripple effect. So if you have no ripple effect in a `ListTile` with an `onTap` handler. you are doing something very strange. (The Ink widget from my class is only required if you want a background color, because when using e.g. `Container` with `color` the ripple effect would be drawn below that color, and hence not being visible). If you don't change your background color, and have a `onTap` in your `ListTile` or `InkWell` you should have a ripple effect.

Comment: I think this is the best solution because It not only change background color for ListTile, but also keep ripple effect when tap on the ListTile

Comment: Remember at least on of the ancestors need to be a Material widget, otherwise this will not work

Comment: There is no need to wrap it with Ink widget. As soon as you add `onTap` listener, the tile should show the ripple effect as expected.

Comment: @oyalhi not if you have a decoratedbox or container with background color.

Answer (score 13):

This is no more pain!

Now you can use `tileColor` and `selectedTileColor` property of `ListTile` widget to achieve it.

Have a look at this [Issue #61347](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/61347) which got merged into master.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer **if** you are running the  `master` branch. The `stable` and `beta` Flutter branches do not support this as of July 29, 2020.

Comment: The only problem I encounter that the splash is removed using tileColor. Otherwise it is the best answer.

Answer (score 12):

Wrap `ListTile` in an [`Ink`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Ink-class.html).

```dart
Ink(
  color: isSelected ? Colors.blue : Colors.transparent,
  child: ListTile(title: Text('hello')),
)
```

Comment: I think this is actually a better answer since Ink communicates well that it will give the child widget a color.

Comment: Also, Ink paints below the material splash effects, while Container paints above :)

Comment: I did try this but I noticed that when using Ink and a scrollable listview the ink stays visible even when the element is out of the view area. I decided to go with a container instead because of that reason.

Answer (score 8):

An easy way would be to store the initial index in a variable and then change the state of that variable whenever tapped.

```
   ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 4,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container( //I have used container for this example. [not mandatory]
                    color: tappedIndex == index ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                    child: ListTile(
                        title: Center(
                      child: Text('${index + 1}'),
                    ),onTap:(){
                          setState((){
                            tappedIndex=index;
                          });
                        }));
              })
```

full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyWidgetState createState() => MyWidgetState();
}

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  late int tappedIndex;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tappedIndex = 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
          ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 4,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                    color: tappedIndex == index ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                    child: ListTile(
                        title: Center(
                      child: Text('${index + 1}'),
                    ),onTap:(){
                          setState((){
                            tappedIndex=index;
                          });
                        }));
              })
        ]));
  }
}
```

Dartpad link: https://dartpad.dev/250ff453b97cc79225e8a9c657dffc8a

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, ListTile doesn't have background-color property. Hence, we have to simply wrap the ListTile widget into a Container/Card widget and then we can use its color property.
Further, We have to provide SizedBox widget with some height to separate the same colored ListTiles.

I am sharing that worked for me :)

I hope it will definitely help you.

Screenshot: [see how it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrQla.jpg)

```
            return 
              ListView(
                children: snapshot.data.documents.map((doc) {
                  return Column(children: [
                    Card(
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                       child: ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                      title: Text(doc.data['coursename'], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),),
                      subtitle: Text('Price: ${doc.data['price']}'),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          await Firestore.instance
                              .collection('courselist')
                              .document(doc.documentID)
                              .delete();
                        },
                      ),
                  ),
                    ),
                 SizedBox(height: 2,)
                  ],);
                }).toList(),[enter image description here][1]
              );
```

Answer (score 5):

I know that the original question has been answered, but I wanted to add **how to set the color of `ListTile` while the tile is being pressed**. The property you are looking for is called `highlight color` and it can be set by wrapping the `ListTile` in a `Theme` widget, like this:

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
    highlightColor: Colors.red,
  ),
  child: ListTile(...),
  )
);
```

**Note:** if the `Theme` widget resets the font of text elements inside the `ListTile`, just set its `fontFamily` property to the same value You used in other places in your app.

Answer (score 3):

I have used as

```
ListTile(
                title: Text('Receipts'),
                leading: Icon(Icons.point_of_sale),
                tileColor: Colors.blue,
              ),
```

Comment: This not a correct answer based on old questions requirements

Answer (score 3):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfGRG.gif)>Make variable

```
        int slectedIndex;
```

> on tap

```
     onTap:(){
                      setState(() {
                      selectedIndex=index;
                     })
```

> Tile property

```
            color:selectedIndex==index?Colors.red :Colors.white,
```

> Same As in List View Builder

```
        ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: 10,
                          scrollDirection:Axis.vertical,
                          itemBuilder: (context,index)=>GestureDetector(
                            onTap:(){
                              setState(() {
                                selectedIndex=index;
                              });
                              
                            } ,
                            child: Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                color:selectedIndex==index?Colors.red :Colors.white,
                              ),)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer has been answered in [Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33392#issuecomment-567103946).

```
Card(
  color: Colors.white,
  shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
  ),
  borderOnForeground: true,
  elevation: 0,
  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,0),
  child: ListTile(
    // ...
  ),
)
```

Comment: From Review: Can you also please provide the explanation along with this code? Links may get broken,  and your answer may get difficult to understand in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There are two props: tileColor and selectedTileColor.

`tileColor` - when the tile/row is Not selected;

`selectedTileColor` - when the tile/row is selected

```
ListTile(
        selected: _isSelected,
        tileColor: Colors.blue,
        selectedTileColor: Colors.greenAccent,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the Background Color of ListTile by making it a child of Container Widget and adding color to the Container Widget.

Here drawerItem is the model class which holds the isSelected value. Color of background depends on isSelected value.

Note: For unselected items keep the color Transparent so you will still get the ripple effect.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < drawerItems.length; i++) {
      var drawerItem = drawerItems[i];
      drawerOptions.add(new Container(
        color: drawerItem.isSelected
            ? Colors.orangeAccent
            : Colors.transparent,
        child: new ListTile(
          title: new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[Text(drawerItem.title), drawerItem.count],
          ),
          leading: SvgPicture.asset(
            drawerItem.icon,
            width: 34,
            height: 34,
          ),
          onTap: () {
            _handleNavigation(i);
          },
          selected: drawerItem.isSelected,
        ),
      ));
    }
```

[image]

Comment: ripple effect is lost

Answer (score 0):

Use the Material widget with InkWell Widget then put inside it the ListTile as shown here in this example:

```
return Material(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: ListTile(
          hoverColor: Colors.greenAccent,
          onLongPress: longPressCallback,
          title: Text(
            '$taskTitle',
            style: TextStyle(
                decoration: isChecked
                    ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                    : TextDecoration.none),
          ),
          trailing: Checkbox(
              activeColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              value: isChecked,
              onChanged: checkboxCallback)),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Other people are telling to wrap your ListTile into a Container, but there is a inbuilt property, you can use tileColor Property.
Just do :

```
ListTile(
   tileColor : Colors.Red,
   ---other properties---
)
```