# How to get to instance in callback

Tags: flutter

I am trying to toggle selected in a list of ListTile in a Drawer?

```
    ListTile(
      title: Text("Name"),
      leading: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
      onTap: () {
        currentSelected.selected = false
        this.selected = true;
        currentSelected = this; // << How to get the instance of ListTile
      },
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` points to the widget that contains the code in your question.
You can create a variable where you assign the `ListTile`, then you can reference it in `onTap`.

```
ListTile listTile;
listTile = ListTile(
      title: Text("Name"),
      leading: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
      onTap: () {
        currentSelected.selected = false
        this.selected = true;
        currentSelected = listTile
      },
    ),
return listTile;
```

It would be better to use a value to store the selected item, like an `itemId`, instead of a widget reference.

Comment: If using itemId, would you then keep a reference to a list of custom ListTile with an itemId - or maybe use Key?

Comment: I would need more context to fully understand what you try to accomplish. I think you shouldn't need a reference to a widget at all.

Comment: Thanks, I just want to make the selected ListTile stand out, when selected. I feel like there already is a solution to this, as this a common scenario. One have done this, but still: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331612/change-background-color-of-listtile-upon-selection-in-flutter

Comment: I guess I should setState and rebuild, would be nice it it was just a rebuild of ListTile

Comment: Yes, if you want the UI to update, you need `setState()`